# How can i fix CORS policy problem in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, cors, access-control, nuxt3

I have a **Nuxt.js** application. I try to fetch data from an api everytime the user change the page. but i get confronted by a Cors problem:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime/?page=2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```js
const fetchData = async (page) => {
    const { data: recommendations } = await useFetch(
      `https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime/?page=${page}`
    );
    return recommendations;
  };

  const page = ref(1);
  const recommendations = ref([]);

  watch(page, async (newPage) => {
    recommendations.value = await fetchData(newPage);
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)